# Couchbase Operator tool for Kubernetes (cbopctl) does not support "oidc" authentication

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, couchbase, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on IBM Cloud and I'm trying to deploy the Couchbase operator.

When running the command:

```
cbopctl apply --kubeconfig /home/jenkins/.bluemix/cluster.yml -f couchbase-autonomous-operator-kubernetes_1.0.0-linux_x86_64/couchbase-cluster.yaml
```

I get the following error.

```
panic: No Auth Provider found for name "oidc"

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/couchbase/couchbase-operator/pkg/client.MustNew(0xc4201e2e00, 0xc4201e2e00, 0x0)
    /var/tmp/foo/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/couchbase-operator/pkg/client/client.go:21 +0x71
main.(*ApplyContext).Run(0xc4207e8570)
```

How do I authenticate this service?

Comment: you need to enable the oidc auth on API server first

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have your `~/.kube/config` file configured to use OpenID with the oidc authenticator. The `~/.kube/config` is with the [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library uses to authenticate and [cbopctl](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.0/cbopctl.html) uses the client-go library.

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens) explains how to set it up in Kubernetes. If you are using an [IBM cloud managed Kubenetes cluster](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/container-service), it's probably already configured on the kube-apiserver and you would have to follow [this](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cli_install.html#cs_cli_install)

To manually configure `kubectl` you would have to do something like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#option-1-oidc-authenticator).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. To provide the IBM Cloud-specific steps, you can download your config file by using `ibmcloud ks cluster-config <cluster-name>`. That will give you the KUBECONFIG variable to export by copying and pasting. It will also give you the path that you can use to target the config in your couchbase command.